# Website will not display in Internet Explorer 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My first responsive Website validates, works with all browsers and displays fine when run locally on a machine with IE7, but won't work on IE 7 or 8 when run live.

The top 2 rows of the site are there but nothing else appears, I've tried using respond/s.js but I'm assuming it to be a problem with my  links.

A reworked version of the site can be seen [[here]](http://www.urbandreamscapes.com) and if anyone can help it will be GREATLY appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title>Urban Dreamscapes &#151; Web Design and Development for Fun</title>

<meta name="description" content= />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, all" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, all" />
    <script src="scripts/css3-mediaqueries.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: Your link is broken, we can't look at your site.

Comment: Very sorry, I've just corrected it - Thank you!

Comment: what documents mode does the browser open the site on IE 7 and 8  ( both local and live)

Comment: In IE 7, your html tag has a margin-left of -32767px.  That is your issue.

Comment: @JustinBreiland - where did you get that margin-left from? OP has not linked any css or anything... just wondering

Comment: @JustinBreiland - Based on the code snippet OP has posted, I cannot make any assumption on css. Moreover OP says it works fine locally but not when Live deployment

Comment: I went to her site in IE7, the <html> has that margin hiding the content.

Comment: It is being added in style.css

Comment: another thing i noticed is reset.css is loaded after style.css.... ummm that shouldnt be right, right? or am i going insane

Comment: nvm that is on a different page of the site. but something to think about nonetheless

Comment: Thank you! for the help and apologies for the delay (out doing the day job), I'm at a loss regarding the negative value, I've scoured the site files and cannot locate it anywhere - why would it only affect IE7/8? I'll be on it over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page breaks when it loads the html5shiv js library in IE7/8 and in my case, becomes unresponsive.

Try to add all the elements you want to "shiv" before html5shiv.js is included.

```
window.html5 = {
  'elements': abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup main mark meter nav output picture progress section summary template time video' 
};
```

From your rendered markup, I see hgroup, header and footer. It's better to include everything though just to be sure

Comment: Thanks! Roman - This sounds like the one, as a hobbyist developer I need to get to grips with these inclusions for IE - Constantly learning.

Comment: You are very much welcome. I hope it works for you and if it did, please don't forget the vote :)